# Apache URL rewrite does not mask subdirectories

Tags: url, apache, url-rewriting

The admin setup a subdirectory `/sites/default/files/resources` and updated the docroot `.htaccess` to point to this subdirectory so that the domain `www.example.com` points to it.
I do not have access to the docroot `.htaccess`

In the browser, `www.example.com/resources` shows `www.example.com/sites/default/files/resources`

What should I add in the subdirectory `.htaccess` such that URL shows `www.example.com/resources` and uses the `index.html` in `/sites/default/files/resources/index.html`?

#### `docroot/.htaccess:`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/default/files/resources/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/default/files/resources/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: What is in the docroot `.htaccess`?  That isn't the type of change that would usually be made with `.htaccess`  Usually you would add a `VirtualHost` to Apache and set the `DocumentRoot` for that virtual host to `/sites/default/files/resources` to have the files served from that directory.

Comment: DO NOT maintain your configuration in .htaccess files unless you really REALLY have to. It makes managing your site really difficult and impacts performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the main .htaccess file in the document root (docroot) of your website and want to set up a specific rewrite rule for the /resources URL path to point to /sites/default/files/resources/index.html, you can create a separate .htaccess file in the /sites/default/files/resources/ directory. In this directory's .htaccess file, you can add the following rules:

Create or edit the .htaccess file in the /sites/default/files/resources/ directory.

Add the following directives to that .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /resources/

# Redirect /resources to /sites/default/files/resources/index.html
RewriteRule ^$ /sites/default/files/resources/index.html [L]

# Handle other resources if needed (e.g., images, CSS, JavaScript)
# Add rules for your specific needs here
```

These rules will redirect requests to /resources to /sites/default/files/resources/index.html. You can also add additional rules to handle other resources like images, CSS, and JavaScript files if needed.